# Only the rightmost operator working in Excel formula with "Less than" and "equal to"

Tags: excel, boolean, operators

I'm creating a filtered spreadsheet so my business can match pets with potential owners who call in. Unfortunately, my formula is only recognizing the rightmost operator in the formula below. The referenced cells that are not calculating correctly have the values "0" or "1" and they're formatted as number cells.

For example, if I use "<=" then it only calculates based on the "=" part. Any thoughts?

```
=FILTER(FILTER('2. Full Provider List'!$B$2:$J$100, ($B$1='2. Full Provider List'!$A$2:$A$100)*($K$5<='2. Full Provider List'!$V$2:$V$100)*($K$6<='2. Full Provider List'!$U$2:$U$100)*($K$7<='2. Full Provider List'!$S$2:$S$100)*($K$8<='2. Full Provider List'!$T$2:$T$100)*(Pet_Age_Weeks<='2. Full Provider List'!$L$2:$L$100)*($B$10<='2. Full Provider List'!$M$2:$M$100)),{1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1})
```

An additional unexpected issue is that I actually want to use ">=" because when people don't care about an option I put "No" ("0" in the reference cell), so in those cases I want users to see ALL options. For example, if a caller isn't allergic to cats then for Hypoallergenic cat needed if I put "No" then I want them to see all cats. If a caller IS allergic and I put "Yes" ("1") then I only want them to see that subset as identified by ">=". HELP!

Comment: *"Any thoughts?"*  I think you should read the HELP pages for information as to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then edit your question to make it easy for someone to duplicate your problem.

Comment: Please simplify the problem, while it is sometimes helpful, rarely it is the case, you should abstract the specific programming problem away from the story of allergies and complicated sheet names and cell references. You should be able to give us a formula that we can paste in our own sheet that will replicate the issue without us having to rebuild a pet store.

Comment: When I use "=A3<=A4" or "=A4>=A5" or "=A5<>A6" and test they all work fine. Have you checked exactly what you are testing?